# Cannot resolve method 'setchecked(boolean)' Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, boolean

hey the only error occurs here. I have tried placing the code into the other section since I am using a android:onClick method, but its the exact same error, when highlighting over button.setChecked(true); does anybody have a solution? maybe an import error or a checkbox required? Not sure why it will not read is checked. 
|| update: its just where it reads ischecked, it doesn't allow me to compile because it reads when i scroll past it "cannot resolve method "ischecked(boolean)" and is printed in red

```
    button = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean flag = preferences.getBoolean("button1", false);
    if (flag) {
        button.clearCheck();
        button.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        button.setChecked(false);
    }
}

public void D1(View view)
{
    boolean checked = ((ToggleButton)view).isChecked();
    if(checked) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("button1", true);
        editor.apply();
        soundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
    else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("button1", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean("button1", false);
        editor.apply();
```

Comment: Whenever you get a runtime error always include the error stack from the logcat in your post. Also, please be certain to include the entire method when posting a method. The first code segment does not show the method header. The last code segment does not have the final bracket. This information is important. Also, please try to format your code poperly.

Comment: all it is is the one spot in the code where ischecked(true) or ischecked(false) is red. the printing for ischecked is red and that is all.. wondering if it is an import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
private static final String MY_SHARED_PREFERENCES = "SharedPreferences";
private static final String MY_BUTTON_PREF = "button1";

private SharedPreferences preferences;
private ToggleButton toggleButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle, savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_SHARED_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);

    toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean(MY_BUTTON_PREF, isChecked);
            editor.commit();

            if(isChecked){
                soundPool.play(sound1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    boolean flag = preferences.getBoolean(MY_BUTTON_PREF, false);
    toggleButton.setChecked(flag);
}
```

**Explanation**:
This code uses the anonymous method `setOnCheckedChangeListener()`on the `ToggleButton` object to listen to the `onCheckedChanged()` event. This means you do not need the `onClick` attribute in the XML layout file--please remove that!

I have made the `toggleButton` object a class property. This makes it accessible throughout the class. I have also moved `setChecked()` to the `onResume()` override method in order to make certain that is set properly should you leave and then return to the `Activity`.

I have changed `editor.apply()` to `editor.commit()`. I have no idea how many values you have that particular instance of `SharedPreferences`, but in general you should use `commit()` wherever possible because `commit()` is asynchronous and does not block the thread--in this case the main UI thread.

It is good practice to use a constant value (java -> static final) for any value that are used to reference any reusable "names" like used in `SharedPreferences`. That way they will not be misspelled and thus give wrong return values.

Comment: thanks theres no compilation errors!! you helped me out emensly I really appreciate it.. is there any way I can load the toggle buttons with a click of another button?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it turns outs it was just the .xml and differently constructed view selection and setting static parameters for the name and subfile!